# Cross-browser woes. Why is this happening?

Tags: html, css

Please refer to my website http://www.vault-x.com

It appears correct in Firefox but in Chrome it has gone fubar.

I cannot work out why.

Comment: What is the problem here? "has gone fubar" isnt really descriptive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have invalid HTML, which is usually the primary cause of cross-browser rendering issues these days.

[http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vault-x.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.vault-x.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Specifically, you're missing a `>` in this `div`...

```
<div class="spacer"</div>
```

Comment: I should have checked this! Lesson learned. Many thanks.